# When using RadDataGrid in explicit incremental loading, how do I get it to do that first data load?

Tags: uwp, telerik

I'm using RadDataGrid in a UWP app, configured to use a data source that uses incremental loading.

If I configure the data grid for auto incremental loading, the grid loads with the first block of data. However, if I set it to explicit loading, the user has to click on "load more rows" to get the first block of data, which is not very good for the user, particularly since "more" implies there are some already!

Is there a way to trigger the RadDataGrid to load that first block of data automatically even though it is set to explicit?

Comment: It shouldn't behave like this. Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using `IncrementalLoadingCollection` which is the default implementation that need  incremental loading manually. If you don't want the user click "load more rows" for the first block, you can just simply load the first block of data code behind by `LoadMoreItemsAsync` method. For example,

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid
    x:Name="grid"
    IncrementalLoadingMode="Explicit"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   IncrementalLoadingCollection<Data> collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<Data>(
   async count =>
   {
       return (from c in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
               select new Data { Category = "Name " + c }).ToList();
   })
    { BatchSize = 100 };

    this.DataContext = collection;
    collection.LoadMoreItemsAsync(10);
}
```

More details please reference [this article](http://docs.telerik.com/help/windows-8-xaml/raddatagrid-datavirtualization.html).